# Constructing a smooth function with arbitarily small support

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

It is possible to construct a $C^\infty({\mathbb{R}})$ function $f$ such that supp$f \subset [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ and $\int f=\frac{\pi}{2}  $ for an arbitrarily small $\epsilon >0 $ ?
I know we can do this for big $\epsilon$ but I was wondering if we could do this for small $\epsilon$. My concern is with the mere existence of such $f$. Thank you.

Comment: Remember that stretching on $ℝ$ is smooth.

Comment: Certainly. Pick a $C^\infty$ function $g$ such that $\operatorname{supp} g\subseteq [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ and $\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon g(t)\,dt\ne 0$, and consider $f(x)=\frac\pi{2\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon g(t)\,dt}g(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $$
f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,~f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{\frac1{x^2-1}} & |x|<1\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Now you can define $A=\int_{\mathbb R} f$ and $$
g_\varepsilon(x):=\frac{\pi}{2A\varepsilon} f\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)
$$
Since $supp(f)=[-1,1]$ you see $supp(g_\varepsilon)=[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ and $$
\int_{\mathbb R} g =\frac{\pi}{2A}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac1{\varepsilon}f\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2A}\int_{\mathbb R} f=\frac{\pi}2.
$$
So $\varepsilon$ can be near $0$ or arbitrary large as you need it.